# c# is it safe using this.Invoke?

Tags: c#, delegates, thread-safety, invoke

If I want to update the main UI control's value in the main thread from another thread, use the following code

1st Try - It works

```
Label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(()=> Label1.Text = "label"));  
button1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(()=> button1.Text = "button")); 
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(()=> textBox1.Text = "textBox"));
```

2nd Try - It works

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(()=> 
{
    Label1.Text = "label";  
    button1.Text = "button";
    textBox1.Text = "textBox";
}));
```

The 2nd Try looks simple because just need to write "this.Invoke"
  The 2nd Try access Main Thread UI controls simply

Is there any problem using 2nd Try "this.Invoke"?
  I wonder if the 2nd Try is safe
  Is there any possibility that the 2nd Try will cause any problems?

Comment: In this case I would use the second example, yes.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thx for teaching me :)

Comment: In advanced scenarios the first may be required but, assuming you've not accidentally fallen into an advanced scenario (running multiple UI threads), the second should usually suffice.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I was just adding an answer for exactly that scenario :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second approach is safe so long as all of the controls are associated with the same UI thread. That's *almost always* the case, but it doesn't absolutely *have* to be the case.

In practical terms, you're almost certain to know if your code *is* creating different controls in different threads (because it's a very unusual thing to need to do). If you don't know you're doing it, assume for the moment that you're not, and your second form should be fine.